# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized exception

Tags: java, spring

When i call this URL using `RestTemplate` for get inform, I get the following error :

```
try {
        String authLogin = propertiesService.getValue("texnomart_auth_login");
        String authPassword = propertiesService.getValue("texnomart_auth_password");
        String authLoginAndPassword = "Basic " + base64Encoder.encodeToString(propertiesService.getValue(authLogin+":"+authPassword).getBytes());
        String apiKey = propertiesService.getValue("texnomart_api_key");
        String url = propertiesService.getValue("texnomart_check_url");
        String mobilePhone = "";
        String bonusCardNumber = "";
        Boolean contractType = false;

        for (PaymentDto.ValueData data : paymentDto.getFieldValueList()) {
            if (Objects.isNull(data.getFieldAlias())) continue;
            if (data.getFieldAlias().equals("phone")) mobilePhone = data.getValue();
            if (data.getFieldAlias().equals("bc_number")) bonusCardNumber = data.getValue();
        }

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(mobilePhone) || StringUtils.isEmpty(bonusCardNumber)) {
            return additionalSuppliersReturn;
        }

        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        TexnoMartRequestDto texnoMartRequestDto = new TexnoMartRequestDto()
                .setMobilePhone(mobilePhone)
                .setBonusCardNumber(bonusCardNumber)
                .setDate(format.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

In the following, I tried to use basic auth with encode type but this method didn't help either :

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setBasicAuth(authLogin, authPassword);
        headers.set("api-key", apiKey);

        String externalId = generateToken();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        logService.logExternal(mapper.writeValueAsString(texnoMartRequestDto), LogType.REQUEST, externalId, url);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(texnoMartRequestDto, headers), String.class);**//here i get an exception**
        logService.logExternal(response.getBody(), LogType.RESPONSE, externalId, url);
```

But, when hitting this URL in postman,I get Success response :

```
"request": {
            "auth": {
                "type": "basic",
                "basic": [
                    {
                        "key": "password",
                        "value": "123123",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "username",
                        "value": "Apelsinn",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "method": "GET",
            "header": [
                {
                    "key": "api-key",
                    "value": "4d8edae8-df0c4c5e-b4acfaac-bec608e4",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ],
            "body": {
                "mode": "raw",
                "raw": "{"phone": "998935919989","date":"26.10.2021 00:00:01","bc_number": "513168315"}",
                "options": {
                    "raw": {
                        "language": "json"
                    }
                }
            },
            "url": {
                "raw": ["http://vpn.texnomart.uz:8282/ut_trendy_xran_javohir/hs/api/v1.1/debt/"][1],
                "protocol": "http",
                "host": [
                    "vpn",
                    "texnomart",
                    "uz"
                ],
                "port": "8282",
                "path": [
                    "ut_trendy_xran_javohir",
                    "hs",
                    "api",
                    "v1.1",
                    "debt",
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
```

The Success response using Postman is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZk7b.png)

**NB: I am a junior developer that's why any help on this would be appreciated!**

Comment: Does `propertiesService.getValue(authLogin+":"+authPassword)` really return something useful?

Comment: yep bro but i can't paste screen to comment box

Comment: You should paste the entire Exception StackTrace for better understanding of the issue.
Also, print a log and check if your `propertiesService.getValue()` is returning the same values as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with URL or HttpEntity type. So try this see the result.

```
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange( "https://url", 
 HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<TexnoMartRequestDto> 
 (texnoMartRequestDto,headers),  String.class);
```

Comment: i check many time bro but only this exception i get at the moment i have not 3 row in my code editor my friend say me you have username and password and you set login and password with headers.setBasicAuth(authLogin, authPassword); this way how dou you think bro it is true